# BabylonJS - Suppress engine start logs

Tags: unit-testing, logging, babylonjs

I'm running some tests using Babylonjs and the following message gets printed to the console for each test:

```
#null engine:
BJS - [09:12:32]: Babylon.js v4.2.1 - Null engine

#thin engine:
Babylon.js v4.2.1 - WebGL2 - Parallel shader compilation
```

Its a bit noisy, is there a way to turn this off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The null engine logs can be disabled by using the `Logger` object. Just be sure to set the log level before creating your engine.

```js
import { NullEngine, Logger } from '@babylonjs/core'

Logger.LogLevels = Logger.WarningLogLevel
const engine = new NullEngine()
```

Note that this does not suppress the regular engine startup message as that uses `console.log` instead of the `Logger` object, source [here](https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/blob/7c8b0e4c06fc69c9649d98d3ccc02d739169566f/src/Engines/thinEngine.ts#L941). For that case we will need to override log for a moment:

```js
import { Engine } from '@babylonjs/core'


const logFunc = console.log
console.log = ()=>{}
const engine = new Engine()
console.log = logFunc
```